# Using Git Credentials with Azure - how does it work?

Tags: git, azure

I created a web app with azure, following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-python)

1. Cloned a github project to my local PC
2. Created a git deployment user using `az webapp deployment user set --user-name <username> --password <password>`.
3. Created an Azure web app with `az webapp create --name <app_name> --resource-group <group_name> --plan <plan_name> **--deployment-local-git**`
4. Add remote azure to the local repository and pushed the code to Azure.
   `git remote add azure`
   `git push azure master`
5. Result: App is up and running
6. Now I made some changes to the code locally and tried to commit with the Azure CLI.

   `git commit -am "Some comment"`

This failed because of missing user and email configuration.

> ```
> ***** Please tell me who you are.
>
> Run**
>
>   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
>   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
> ```

7. It took me a while to understand I can supply any user and email here. I thought i need to supply a predefined credentials, which I didn't know what they are.  after defining any user and mail commit succeeded.

So I have few question about the process:

1. How can push commits to Azure without supplying the credentials created is step 2 above? What are these for?
2. How come I can set any user and email to perform the local commits, before pushing.
3. As part of my tries I tried use the Git GUI application.
   When I open the local repository I was prompt for user and password. I entered the user and password created in step 2 above. And indeed repository was opened.
4. How many copies does the app have. 2 (local copy and one on Azure) or 3 (extra copy on git hub)

Answer (score 2):

The credentials you specified in step #2 are Azure-specific. Per your link, "This deployment user is required for FTP and local Git deployment to a web app."

When you're setting up your machine to do local Git work, you should [set local credentials](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup). That way you won't get the error you show.

In your example, after cloning the Github repo to your local machine in step #1, Github is no longer involved. You could have done the clone anonymously, or you could have supplied credentials (required if you want to make actual changes to the Github repo). So to answer question #4, there are three copies, but the Github one is irrelevant at this point.

You can push from local Git to Azure, or you can push from Github to Azure (particularly useful for continuous deployment).

Comment: not sure I understand. This only describes what I see, but do not understand. 1. "This deployment user is required for FTP and local Git deployment to a web app." Isn't is exactly what I am doing _local git deployment_? Furture more, this is conceptual question, how can one push changes without supplying credentials? 2. what are local credential stand for? and what about the fact that the GIT GUI asked for user and password (as opposed to user and email). Could I have supplied any user - password to open the repo? 3. # of copies: Question referred the changes,understand the answer. 2 copies.

Comment: Azure does not need to know and does not care what credentials you use locally for git work. You did set the credentials for pushing to Azure, using az webapp deployment...those are now assumed for subsequent pushes. The quotation is possibly unhelpful as could be read as implying that Azure needs to know your local git credentials, but this is not the case.

Comment: 2. Why have local credentials? Git is distributed. Say you work on your machine for a month, make various changes and revisions. Then you push to Github or some other remote repo in order to share your work with team-mates. You might want to let them look in the early history to see why you did something in a particular way. The early changes you made will all be signed off with those credentials.

Comment: I do not understand the concept.1)Usually, user & password (or any kind of credentials) are defined within a system (web site,scm systems(aka github),DataBase or any web server. For one to be able to view, or do changes the predefined credential need to be supplied. Here, one can push anything he wants to azure, without to supply these. I do not understand that. I logout from azure (`az logout`) in the _Azure CLI_,and still could push the changes. 2) I am not saying Azure needs to know the local credential,I do expect the push will require the user & pass defined with `az webapp deployment`

Comment: az logout has nothing to do with it; that just signs the CLI out of your subscription. You've supplied the deployment credentials with az webapp deployment user set --user-name <username> --password <password> until such time as you change. So the push doesn't need it as the credentials are already set, subscription-wide. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/user

Comment: I will try to describe better my (mis)understanding 1.`az webapp deployment User1 Pass1` tells azure whenever one uses these credentials-he's allowed 2.This command is executed within the azure subscription context (ie when one is connected to Azure with his user&pass.This is why I might thought, if I am out of  context (i.e. logout),pushing might not work 3. How does Azure understands one pushes using _User1_ _Pass1_ and not _User2_?Where is the difference with any other system that requires authentication?If I will copy the repository to another machine and try to push,will it also work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169855/discussion-between-ojnsim-and-huysmania).